# how to get all columns and sum data of 1 colu, in hql?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to do this

> Query query = session.createQuery("*, sum(quantity) FROM Inventory ORDER BY price ASC, > entry_time ASC");

keep getting error saying it doesn't recogize *..

> ERROR: line 1:1: unexpected token: * line 1:1: unexpected token: *

so I tried the other way SELECT *, sum(quantity) from Inventory ORDER BY price ASC, entry_time ASC

get same error as above, plus:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:
>   * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT *,SUM(quantity) FROM Inventory ORDER BY price ASC, entry_time ASC]

so how do I retrieve all columns while at the same time sum them if neither work? (the command actually worked in SQLWave.. but not working via Java+Hib)

This is the query I am trying to run (which works using SQL wave)

> SELECT *, sum(quantity) FROM (SELECT * FROM Inventory ORDER BY price
>   ASC, entry_time ASC) AS r group by price

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately when you're using aggregate functions you must specify all the columns you want retrieved. `SELECT *, SUM(quantity)` won't work.

All columns in the SELECT clause that do not have an aggregate need to be in the GROUP BY

Good:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4)
...
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
```

Also good:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4)
...
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col5, col6
```

No other columns = no GROUP BY needed

```
SELECT MAX(col4)
...
```

Won't work:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4)
...
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

Pointless:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4)
...
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, MAX(col4)
```

Having an aggregate (MAX etc) with other columns without a GROUP BY makes no sense because the query becomes ambiguous.

Comment: ERROR: line 1:1: unexpected token: vendor_name
line 1:1: unexpected token: vendor_name

Comment: I just noticed it was HQL and not SQL. Give me a minute.

Comment: query = session.createQuery("vendor_name, entry_time, item, sum(quantity), price FROM Inventory where item=:item ORDER BY price DESC, entry_time ASC AS r group by vendor_name, entry_time, instrument, item, price");

Comment: Without knowing your schema it's tough to say, but it should look something like "SELECT I.vender_name, I.entry_time, I.item, sum(I.quantity), price FROM Inventory I where item = :item ...